# Zip all files in the directory by windows command

Tags: windows, command-line

Zip all the files in the specific directory and I need to place the zip file in the same folder through windows command prompt.
I know command for unzip as below

```
"unzip SRCPath -d DestPath "
```

I am looking all the text files to compress and place the zip file in the same folder.